# Delayed output with Media Foundation H.264 Video Decoder

Tags: video, h.264, ms-media-foundation

I am streaming my content using H.264 encoder and wish to decode the content using H.264 decoder.
The encoding topology is like

Source --> H.264 Encoder --> NetDump

and the decoding topology is like

NetSource --> H.264 Decoder --> EVR

We are able to make our the  decoding topology but output video produce the delay around more than 1 sec .Please suggest some solution for that delay. Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 5):

According to Matt Andrews from MSFT Media Foundation team, this is due to internal buffering within the Microsoft [H.264 Decoder MFT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd797815%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (see [Rendering Delay when using h264 Decoder](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/mediafoundationdevelopment/thread/0d9cd54f-2435-4867-bf15-4c6a0532520f)).

When using Windows 8 there is a [low latency mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh447590%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that could help you. 
I had the same problem and skipped the MSFT H.264 Decoder MFT completely.

Comment: Joachim K.: How did you skipped the h264 decoder mft?

Comment: i used a custom made h264 decoder MFT (using ffmpeg) instead of the decoder MFT delivered with windows.